# How do I change an input from active high to a positive edge trigger?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

know that flip flops are edge-triggered, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know how to replicate that for my own circuits.

On a gate level, how does a pos-edge happen?

Comment: Read this: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/edge-triggered-latches-flip-flops/

Comment: You already know enough to answer this yourself. find a gate-level implementation of a flip-flop.